# Why is std::packaged_task<void()> not valid?

Tags: c++, c++11, packaged-task

Using MSVC2012,

The following code will compile and run as expected

```
std::packaged_task< int() > task( []()->int{ std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; return 0; } );
std::thread t( std::move(task) );
t.join();
```

while the following code will fail to compile and run

```
std::packaged_task< void() > task( [](){ std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; } );
std::thread t( std::move(task) );
t.join();
```

Why is this so?

Edit:
As a workaround, it is possible to use std::promise to get a std::future on a function that returns void

```
std::promise<void> promise;
auto future = promise.get_future();
std::thread thread( [](std::promise<void> &p){ std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; p.set_value(); }, std::move(promise) );
future.wait();
```

Note that there is a bug in the vs2012 library with std::thread that forces you to pass the promise in as a l-value reference and move the promise in, it would not compile if you pass the promise by value or by r-value reference. This is supposedly because the implementation uses std::bind() which does not behave as expected.

Comment: Interesting...what error does the second one give when compiling?

Comment: This is a bug in MSVC++ probably.

Comment: From what I traced into their implementation of <future>, it eventually comes down to their storage of function object execution state, specifically in a template class called `_State_manager`. There is no specialization of `_State_manager` for `void` state, which is likley a bug. I could be completely out to lunch too, but thats where it appears everything falls apart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in MSVC2012. There are quite a few bugs in the thread library implementation that ships with MSVC2012. I posted a partial list in my blog post comparing it to my commercial Just::Thread library: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/just-thread-v1.8.0-released.html

Comment: "With the VS2012 library, when std::async is used with a launch policy of std::launch::async, the destructor of the returned std::future instance does not wait for the thread to complete." -- I would make that an option.  The argument that the standards text has a bug in it is compelling.

Comment: The standard wording for `std::async` was carefully chosen, and Microsoft deliberately decided to go against the standard. This is not a bug in the standard, though some believe it was a bad choice.

Comment: This is disappointing, some of these bugs would have been caught by the simplest of test cases. I expected more from Microsoft.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams The committee (notably Herb Sutter, who is obviously affiliated with Microsoft), seems to be discussing whether this behavior is indeed a bug in the standard itself. Herb is pushing for Microsoft's implementation to be the new definition of the standard for C++14: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3391.html#Herb5

Comment: @BretKuhns I'm well aware of that paper. It was discussed extensively, and there was no consensus for change. I expect Herb will come back with another paper, but it's stalled for now.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams I expected you would. At the least, I thought it was worth noting for others. Microsoft's implementation isn't compliant, but it's preferable IMO, so it would be nice to see the committee do something about that.

Answer (score 4):

This works in gcc 4.7.2:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::packaged_task< void() > task( [](){ std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; } );
  std::thread t( std::move(task) );
  t.join();
  std::packaged_task< int() > task2( []()->int{ std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; return 0; } );
  std::thread t2( std::move(task2) );
  t2.join();
}
```

Together with @WhozCraig 's archeology implies that this is probably a bug in MSVC2012.

For a workaround, try using `struct Nothing {};` or `nullptr_t` as your return value?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is still there in MSVS 2013RC, but I made this temporary patch while MS corrects it. It is a specialization of packaged_task for void(...), so I suggest putting this in a header file and including it after the standard headers.Note that make_ready_at_thread_exit() is not implemented and some functions have not been fully tested, use at your own risk.

```
namespace std {

template<class... _ArgTypes>
class packaged_task<void(_ArgTypes...)>
{
    promise<void> _my_promise;
    function<void(_ArgTypes...)> _my_func;

public:
    packaged_task() {
    }

    template<class _Fty2>
    explicit packaged_task(_Fty2&& _Fnarg)
      : _my_func(_Fnarg) {
    }

    packaged_task(packaged_task&& _Other)
      : _my_promise(move(_Other._my_promise)),
        _my_func(move(_Other._my_func)) {
    }

    packaged_task& operator=(packaged_task&& _Other) {
        _my_promise = move(_Other._my_promise);
        _my_func = move(_Other._my_func);
        return (*this);
    }

    packaged_task(const packaged_task&) = delete;
    packaged_task& operator=(const packaged_task&) = delete;

    ~packaged_task() {
    }

    void swap(packaged_task& _Other) {
        _my_promise.swap(_Other._my_promise);
        _my_func.swap(_Other._my_func);
    }

    explicit operator bool() const {
        return _my_func != false;
    }

    bool valid() const {
        return _my_func != false;
    }

    future<void> get_future() {
        return _my_promise.get_future();
    }

    void operator()(_ArgTypes... _Args) {
        _my_func(forward<_ArgTypes>(_Args)...);
        _my_promise.set_value();
    }

    void reset() {
        swap(packaged_task());
    }
};

}; // namespace std
```